# Can't see the ListView in my Fragment

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to show a listView in Fragment but when I ran the application, it give a blank page instead.I'm populating ListView with array adapter from string in fragment.

Here is my code:

```
public class CardContentFragment extends Fragment {


private String[] items;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.item_card, container, false);


    items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);


    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


    ListAdapter myListAdapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

    lv.setAdapter(myListAdapter);


    return view;


}


}
```

**array.xml**

```
<string-array name="list">
        <item>Argentina (54 11) 4863 3291</item>
        <item>Aruba (297) 839 662</item>
        <item>Australia (61 2) 9416 2373</item>



    </string-array>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:fillViewport="true">


    </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

there is no error, I think it's just a layout issue but I can't solve.

Comment: Show a code, how you are attaching fragment inside Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, It was just a typo:

```
ListAdapter myListAdapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

I just put "items" instead of "list"

Answer (score 4):

you need to pass your `items` to your adapter

```
ListAdapter myListAdapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
                                             ^^^^^ this has your array
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);


   ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


    ListAdapter myListAdapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

    lv.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

and put your in your string.xml

```
<string-array name="list">
    <item>Argentina (54 11) 4863 3291</item>
    <item>Aruba (297) 839 662</item>
    <item>Australia (61 2) 9416 2373</item>



</string-array>
```